# Update a recyclerView in another activity from async thread of other activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-async-http

I have two activity A and B.

In activity A I have a AsyncHttpClient fetching some data from a website. Once the data is received, I refresh the RecyclerView in activity A. But while the data is being fetched if someone switches to activity B, i want the RecyclerView of activity B to be refreshed on completion of data fetch.

Currently I am able to update in the same activity A, but can't do that in B.

Here is what I have done -

```
public void loadFromWeb(){
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            params.put("id", id);

            client.post("http://example.com/process.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        //process the response

                        adapterInActivityA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //This works for Activity A

                        //How to implement the function updateInActivityB()?  
                        updateInActivityB();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //catch exception
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                    // Process failure
                }

            });
}
```

The problem is how to implement function updateInActivityB()

---

### Solution (As suggested by Alok)

Following are the details of what I did for others who want to do the same -

This uses [greenrobot's EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Compile the library by adding it to the app's build.gradle file

Compile the library

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
```

Create your event class, this will store the data which you are communicating.

```
//In FirstActivity

public class myEvent {
    private final String data;

    //Constructor
    public myEvent(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to send an update the data has been downloaded (i.e. in updateInSecondActivity() function)

**post the update -**

```
//In FirstActivity

public void updateInSecondActivity(){
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new myEvent("Updated Data");
}
```

Now, In the SecondActivity, you have to listen for this event. First Register in the SecondActivity to subscribe to the events -

**Register for the events**

```
//In SecondActivity

EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

You can register in onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(). Also don't forget to unregister in onPause(), onDestroy(), onStop() -

**Unregister the event listener**

```
//In SecondActivity

EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

Once the registration and unregistration is in place, you have to listen if the update has been posted by FirstActivity or not. You can do this by creating an onEvent() function which listens for posting of myEvent class -

**Listen to the event**

```
//In SecondActivity

public void onEvent(myEvent mE){
    String updatedData = me.getData();
    // Process/update using the updateData
}
```

Comment: You can write some singletone with listeners (bad pattern) or write custom Service

Comment: You need to move the Data/Network logic away from any Activity if you want to share data between them IMHO.  I'd use a MVP approach, or if you don't want this you could use a SQLite database and create a Content Provider along with CursorAdapters/ContentObservers. There are of course other ways, but this is how I'd approach it.

Comment: Thanks, I used the event bus to manage inter-activity communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try to make a broadcast receiver that can receive a broadcast
   Message fired by your asynchronous thread.

Or

2.you can use event bus to limitless  communication.

Or

3.you can register an observer for content received .

Logic is pretty simple
You try to fetch the data if data fetched before user switch to next  activity than everything is fine.

In second case when user switches earlier, than in this case you can check for content while resuming next activity. If content not received yet than you can implement any of above 3 method observer ultimately when content received your observer will be notified.

Comment: Thanks, I used the event bus to manage inter-activity communication

Comment: You should accept and vote the answer , it will help other too